# Using flowfiles default attributes inside code

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to  use  filesize inside my groovy  code so  I've added updateAttribute inside with such expression `${filesize:toNumber()}`  and  i want to use   this  attribute in my  groovy code  shown  below:

```
def size=flowFile.getAttribute('filesize');
int value = size as Integer;
if(value.div(4)<=1)
```

but executescript   processor gives me nosuchProperty exception;
One more  thing i want to know:will `def flowFile=session.get(1)` get the  one  fowfile at a time?

Comment: Yes, `session.get(1)` will return a single flowfile, but in a `List<FlowFile>` (from [ProcessSession.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.3.0/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.java#L189))

Answer (score 2):

Apache NiFi's built-in flowfile property for content length in bytes is `fileSize` (case-sensitive).

Comment: can i  check if  filesize is in   byte  and   convert it to   byte  if  it  isn't? how can i  check this?

Comment: `fileSize` is internally maintained by the NiFi framework.  It is always in bytes.